# Istio Circuit Breaker Blacklist/whitelist error codes

Tags: istio

Is there a way in which we can provide Istio to blacklist or whitelist an error code. Since I have tried with 500(Internal Server Error) but circuit breaker is not getting open in 500 as well?

Answer (score 0):

The [Circuit Breaker](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/cluster/circuit_breaker.proto) doesn't have that kind of functionality.

Furthermore there is an issue with `Error 500` not being used in Circuit Breaker. There is an issue about this on [github](https://github.com/istio/api/issues/909).

> We try not to expose the plethora of sometimes confusing Envoy options
>   to end users, in the routing api.
>
> Within a mesh, gateway errors will be more common (502/503/504) while
>   most sensible external services will return a 503 to shed load.
>
> Secondly we just made the outlier detection generic to both tcp and
>   http. The consecutive gateway error applies only to http and will make
>   no sense in tcp context.
>
> I also feel that 500 error code is not something indicative of
>   overload. The whole idea behind outliers is to remove overloaded
>   servers from the lb pool.
>
> We don’t have very many users relying on this behavior I think. We
>   kept it intentionally generic so that we can switch to a more specific
>   error code in future (which happens to be now).

Hope this helps.